postfix->spamassassin mail goes into loop
I had a working postfix installation and I added spamassassin by including the following in master.cf
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -o content_filter=spamassassin
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=spamd argv=/usr/local/bin/spamc -4 -f -e
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

What happens is that when email gets delivered from external SMTP, then it goes into spamassassin (everything works good here) and after scanning and scoring is delivered through sendmail by remote delivery (this is a little strange, should not be a local delivery?) and then is being scanned again, and it loops several times until postfix throws "remote delivery failed 554 5.4.0 Error: too many hops" error.
There are no clues, or errors in the logs, other than the remote delivery information from sendmail.
I had an idea that maybe my local server IP is not trusted, however postfix seems to be properly set up with correct mynetworks
mynetworks = 127.0.0.255
 127.0.0.0/8
 here-the-server-ip

There is clearly sendmail being used in master.cf (as per several guides) and sendmail will not do a local delivery, therefore how is postfix supposed to know that the email has already been scanned by spamassassin?
I spent some time researching this but have no more ideas, any tips are appreciated.

You don't need to modify master.cf. See Archlinux - SpamAssassin setup.
